# Увеличения скорости создания индекса в Postgres

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

За счет чего можно уменьшить время создания индекса в  Postgres? У меня база на локальном компе (ОС Windows 8). Есть таблица в базе данных, в ней 2 колонки ( ID, Text). Создаю индекс gin на Text.

```
CREATE INDEX "Text_idx" 
ON "Table" 
USING gin ((to_tsvector('russian_hunspell'::regconfig, ("Text")::text)));
```

В таблице у меня 10 строчек ( в каждой строчке текст из различных файлов). Размер такой ячейки, где этот текст большой, и часть текста идет в TOAST таблицу.

Создание индекса, для такой колонки Text где-то 150 сек.

Подскажите за счет чего можно сделать это время меньше? Чтобы индекс создавался быстрее.

Comment: Начну с непопулярного вопроса: а зачем?  Ну работает 3 минуты, чем вам поможет то что операция нужная всего один раз будет чуть быстрее? Вы вероятно вопрос дольше писали.

Comment: SSD диск поможет.